# nodejs creating wafeform from mp3 in svg

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, svg

i'm making a research for the topic of getting a mp3 file rendered as waveform. i've already found some php libraries. now i'm looking for a similar solution in nodejs.

my results so far are:

- https://github.com/afreiday/php-waveform-svg
- http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ (maybe loading this in nodejs to try rendering the wave file in svg-format... not quiet sure)

have you guys experience with nodejs-libraries to create waveforms in svg format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a directly nodejs-related solution.

We use a Linux commandline tool [Sonic Annotator](http://www.vamp-plugins.org/sonic-annotator/) to extract waveform (peaks) and detect beat in audio files. Its a host that can run [VAMP plugins](http://www.vamp-plugins.org) that are quite good at these tasks.

Peaks are extracted as a set of floats from 0 to 1 at equal intervals. SHould be rather simple to build an svg on top of that data (with [D3](http://d3js.org/) i.e.).

I'm not used to nodejs, but [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) says it can run external commands.

Comment: hi serge! thanks for your answer. seems like this will help me a lot! i'm going to test everything in a small project to get to know if nodejs can perform general html5-tasks like audio-parsing. thanks dude/dudette!